# Stack memory with iostream

Tags: c++

I've recently hit a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) on a line equivalent to

```
some_file << some_number << ": ";
```

When the stack memory allocated to this application (it's on a pseudo-embedded system) is increased to 512 kB, we don't segmentation fault.

When writing to a file with the operator (<<), how is stack memory usage affected?

The some_file being written to is a std::ofstream. The some_number being written is passed by reference to the method where this sample line of code lives. The software is 32-bit and compiled with g++ on CentOS.

I'm curious how (or if) ofstream uses dynamic allocation, even in higher-level, general terms.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer this? We don't know what your code looks like, which hardware you run it on, how you compile it on, or how your standard library is implemented.

Comment: Points taken.  I provided some more details in response to @dutt below. I'm basically curious about any potential dynamic memory allocation/stack usage that may go on under the covers when writing to a file using the std::ofstream class.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to just upvote [jalf's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788440/stack-memory-with-iostream#comment32966444_21788440), but there are some things that are known. Unless the systems implementation of [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) or the compiler is really unusual.

Unless it's inlined, and that's up to the compiler, there's a function call which means pushing a bunch of things to the stack. How much the call requires depends on the number of registers, size of registers and so on.

But more stack could be used inside the call to `operator<<`. All local variables use stack, and other function calls inside of the `operator<<` use the stack, unless they're inlined. And so on.

It depends on the implementation of whichever class `some_file` is an instantiation of. Without more details we can't say anything specific.

Comment: Nothing is inlined here.  The some_file being written to is a std::ofstream.  The some_number being written is passed by reference to this particular call.  The software is 32bit and compiled with g++ on CentOS.  I'm looking for ofstream uses memory under the hood (is it using a lot of dynamic allocation?) and if it's possible to blow ton of stack writing to a file this way (with repeated calls using '<<' and flushing occassionally).

Comment: Have you used a profiler to check how close to the limit you are when running with the smaller stack?

Comment: Also, if it's centos-based that should mean it's a normal gnu libc implementation, which should be open source, so you could just look up the implementation of operator<< for whichever overload you're using

Comment: I've used vagrind's massif tool but it didn't seem to agree necessarily with the behavior I see with regard to dying in a call to write to the file. I'll look around for any information on the GNU libc ostream implementation wrt memory usage. Thanks